# Does the opening angle of the cone matter?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics

When discussing orbital mechanics, you learn that all orbits roughly follow an ellipse which is obtained as the intersection of a cone with an inclined plane, creating conic sections.
[image]

Below is a plot of different mathematical variables of a cone. I am trying to figure out if the ellipses formed by orbits follow a special rule where the opening angle (at the top of the diagram) of the cone is 90 degrees, or if it is irrelevant what that angle is.

[image]

Comment: [Cross-posted on Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114683/21740). Please avoid cross-posting same question on multiple [SE] sites, as it makes it difficult for our readers to follow and find the best answer to it. Thanks!

Comment: Yea I know it's not a great thing to do. I was trying to prove a point that having different communities answer the same question could be useful :\. The Physics answer is much more appropriate, so I am willing to delete this question if you would like.

Comment: No, I wouldn't and HopDavid went into trouble of answering it here, so I'm not the one to ask, and two accepted answers on both sites make merger impossible. Freely experimenting with our platform also goes against what the whole communities are working on here on [se], and once it's done, there's really no appropriate way of handling it any more. Suggestions for improvement of our site and the way it's meant to function belong in our [meta], where the whole community can chip in with their take. And for [se]-wide issues, please use [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sounds good. The idea came from the Meta Stack Exchange. I was wondering how to handle questions  that could be answered by two different forums. I was unaware that you could merge a question between multiple appropriate sites.

Comment: Members of [space.se] can participate on [physics.se] and vice versa, so cross-posting the same question can't possibly be in anyone's interests, not yours due to inadequate cross-site peer-review, and even less so of those also interested in the answers and might have problems finding all of them, or deciding which one is better because of the cross-talk. It would also help if you asked around (in [meta], our [chat],...) before, why cross-posting isn't recommended. There's no need for new experiments of this kind, when it's been empirically proven many times before that it doesn't work.

Comment: Noted. I thought it would be rather harmless but I can see that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of the cone as a flashflight beam and the cutting plane as the floor:

[image]

Shine the beam straight down and you get a circle. Tilt the beam and the circle stretches into an ellipse. Tilt it more and the ellipse gets longer and longer.

When the top edge of the light beam becomes parallel with the floor, the ellipse stretches out to infinity and you have a parabola of eccentricity one.

Thus by varying the tilts you can get any ellipse from eccentricity 0 to 1. Doesn't matter how thin the cone is, so long as it's angle is more than zero.

Comment: There is a rat and morse code in your otherwise pedagogical illustration.

Comment: The morse code are the words Circle, Ellipse and Parabola viewed from the top. He may be a rat but he's a friendly rat! His name is Jimmy DeGriz. I put him for a couple of reasons: A reference object makes it a little clearer that each conic is viewed from the top and the side (I hope). That rat's shadow is intended to reinforce the notion of a conic light beam.

Comment: Also when I ask for input from my friends and family they complain my geometry illustrations are very dry. It's an attempt to lighten up and not be so serious.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all, which is asking if the cone angle is an important parameter for describing the shapes of the orbits and if it matters.

Comment: And as I explained, the cone angle doesn't matter. By positioning the cutting plane, you can get any sort of ellipse you want